# Selenium with headless chrome doesn't wait for javascript

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to extract a variety of information from a site. The site uses Javascript and allows you to search for a series of addresses on a map. What I have to do is: 1) enter a text in a text box 2) press the search button 3) wait for the list of addresses and the map to update (Gmaps) 4) extract data from the list When I use Selenium and chrome in the normal version, everything works. for point 3, to wait until the page is completely loaded, i use the following block of code:

```
public void waitForLoading() {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            boolean condition = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            System.out.println(condition);
            return condition;
        }
    };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

When I use Chrome headless, using exactly the same code, selenium doesn't wait. point 3 is always evaluated true, i.e. the above function return always true, also if the list is not loaded. The only solution that i found is to use Thread.sleep(), but is not the best and is very strange that the first solution doesn't work

could someone help me understand how to solve the problem?

Comment: Thread.sleep may be your best bet. An uglier solution would be to to throw it into a while loop until true or until there’s a value.

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID thanks for the comment. Yes that could be a solution but I would like to understand why the code that works in the normal version does not work in the Headless version. Furthermore, using the code that I indicated in the question would be more correct in general.